Prisma generated SQL request is incorrect
I'm using Prisma as my ORM to fetch data from a table, including its relations. Here are the args of my findMany call:
{
  take: 50,
  skip: 0,
  include: {
    AprRecords: {
      take: 1,
      orderBy: [Object ...],
      include: [Object ...],
    },
    TvlRecords: {
      take: 1,
      orderBy: [Object ...],
      include: [Object ...],
    },
    DailyRewardsRecords: {
      take: 1,
      orderBy: [Object ...],
      include: [Object ...],
    },
    MainProtocol: true,
    Chain: true,
    Protocols: true,
    Tokens: true,
  },
  orderBy: {
    dailyRewards: "desc",
  },
  where: {
    OR: undefined,
  },
}

Here are the generated SQL requests:
prisma:query SELECT "public"."Opportunity"."id", "public"."Opportunity"."chainId", "public"."Opportunity"."type"::text, "public"."Opportunity"."identifier", "public"."Opportunity"."name", "public"."Opportunity"."status"::text, "public"."Opportunity"."action"::text, "public"."Opportunity"."mainProtocolId", "public"."Opportunity"."tvl", "public"."Opportunity"."apr", "public"."Opportunity"."dailyRewards", "public"."Opportunity"."tags" FROM "public"."Opportunity" WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY "public"."Opportunity"."dailyRewards" DESC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2

prisma:query SELECT "public"."AprRecord"."id", "public"."AprRecord"."timestamp", "public"."AprRecord"."cumulated", "public"."AprRecord"."opportunityId" FROM "public"."AprRecord" WHERE "public"."AprRecord"."opportunityId" IN ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50) ORDER BY "public"."AprRecord"."timestamp" DESC OFFSET $51

prisma:query SELECT "public"."AprBreakdown"."id", "public"."AprBreakdown"."identifier", "public"."AprBreakdown"."type"::text, "public"."AprBreakdown"."value", "public"."AprBreakdown"."aprRecordId" FROM "public"."AprBreakdown" WHERE "public"."AprBreakdown"."aprRecordId" IN ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50) OFFSET $51

prisma:query SELECT "public"."TVLRecord"."id", "public"."TVLRecord"."timestamp", "public"."TVLRecord"."total", "public"."TVLRecord"."opportunityId" FROM "public"."TVLRecord" WHERE "public"."TVLRecord"."opportunityId" IN ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50) ORDER BY "public"."TVLRecord"."timestamp" DESC OFFSET $51

prisma:query SELECT "public"."TVLBreakdown"."id", "public"."TVLBreakdown"."identifier", "public"."TVLBreakdown"."type"::text, "public"."TVLBreakdown"."value", "public"."TVLBreakdown"."tvlRecordId" FROM "public"."TVLBreakdown" WHERE "public"."TVLBreakdown"."tvlRecordId" IN ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50) OFFSET $51

prisma:query SELECT "public"."DailyRewardsRecord"."id", "public"."DailyRewardsRecord"."timestamp", "public"."DailyRewardsRecord"."total", "public"."DailyRewardsRecord"."opportunityId" FROM "public"."DailyRewardsRecord" WHERE "public"."DailyRewardsRecord"."opportunityId" IN ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50) ORDER BY "public"."DailyRewardsRecord"."timestamp" DESC OFFSET $51

prisma:query SELECT "public"."DailyRewardsBreakdown"."id", "public"."DailyRewardsBreakdown"."value", "public"."DailyRewardsBreakdown"."campaignId", "public"."DailyRewardsBreakdown"."dailyRewardsRecordId" FROM "public"."DailyRewardsBreakdown" WHERE "public"."DailyRewardsBreakdown"."dailyRewardsRecordId" IN ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50) OFFSET $51

prisma:query SELECT "public"."Protocol"."id", "public"."Protocol"."tags"::text[], "public"."Protocol"."name", "public"."Protocol"."description", "public"."Protocol"."url", "public"."Protocol"."icon" FROM "public"."Protocol" WHERE "public"."Protocol"."id" IN ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10) OFFSET $11

prisma:query SELECT "public"."Chain"."id", "public"."Chain"."name", "public"."Chain"."icon" FROM "public"."Chain" WHERE "public"."Chain"."id" IN ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11) OFFSET $12

prisma:query SELECT "public"."_OpportunityToProtocol"."A", "public"."_OpportunityToProtocol"."B" FROM "public"."_OpportunityToProtocol" WHERE "public"."_OpportunityToProtocol"."A" IN ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50)

prisma:query SELECT "public"."_OpportunityToToken"."A", "public"."_OpportunityToToken"."B" FROM "public"."_OpportunityToToken" WHERE "public"."_OpportunityToToken"."A" IN ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50)

prisma:query SELECT "public"."Token"."id", "public"."Token"."name", "public"."Token"."chainId", "public"."Token"."address", "public"."Token"."decimals", "public"."Token"."symbol", "public"."Token"."icon", "public"."Token"."verified", "public"."Token"."price" FROM "public"."Token" WHERE "public"."Token"."id" IN ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$53,$54,$55,$56,$57,$58,$59,$60,$61,$62,$63,$64,$65,$66,$67,$68,$69,$70,$71,$72,$73,$74,$75,$76,$77,$78,$79,$80,$81,$82,$83,$84,$85,$86,$87,$88) OFFSET $89

As you can see, there is a take: 1 clause in the args of the included relations (AprRecords, TvlRecords, DailyRewardsRecords). However, there is no LIMIT clause in the generated SQL request, resulting in tens of thousands of rows returned instead of 1.
Prisma's findMany() method returns the correct result, but do the take: 1 at the application level instead of the database level.
How can I retrieve only one record in a nested read at the database level ?

This issue is known by the Prisma team and is not solved yet:
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/15623
